# I want to change the background color of the table given in csss from an value from select

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is this  script

```
<script> 
  function abcd() 
   {
     var col=document.getElementById("chess").value;
      document.getElementById("chess").style.background:col;
   }

</script>
```

the css where i defined the color i need to change as per the value retrieved from the select

```
table
  {
    margin: 80px auto;
    background:black;
  }
```

need to access the value selected

```
<select id="chess" >
   <option name="abc"  value="black"> <i><b>BLACK</b></i></option>
   <option name="abc"  value="red"><i><b>RED</b></i></a></option>
   <option  name="abc" value="yellow"><i><b>YELLOW</b></i></option>
</select>
```

this is table where i need to change  color after the selection / submit of the value

```
<table id="ta">
 <tr class="chessboard">
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
    <td class="chessboard"></td>
</tr>
</table
```

Comment: `background:col;` should probably be `background = col;`, no? Where is `abcd()` called? The example appears to be incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues in your code:

1. You are not calling the function anywhere in your code.
2. You probably want to set the background to the table which is having id `chessboard` not `chess`. You also have to use assignment operator (`=`) not `:`.
3. You have unnecessary `</a>` inside the second option.
4. You have missed the closing `>` in `</table`.

Try the following way:

```js
function abcd(op) {
  var col=op.options[op.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById("ta").style.background = col;
}
```

```css
table{
  margin: 80px auto;
  background:black;
}
```

```html
<select id="chess" onchange="abcd(this)">
   <option name="abc"  value="black"> <i><b>BLACK</b></i></option>
   <option name="abc"  value="red"><i><b>RED</b></i></option>
   <option  name="abc" value="yellow"><i><b>YELLOW</b></i></option>
</select>
<table id="ta">
   <tr class="chessboard">
      <td class="chessboard">1</td>
      <td class="chessboard">2</td>
      <td class="chessboard">3</td>
      <td class="chessboard">4</td>
      <td class="chessboard">5</td>
      <td class="chessboard">6</td>
      <td class="chessboard">7</td>
      <td class="chessboard">8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help i m just new on web development and a student i m really grateful for your guidance

Comment: @PranavHarer, If the answer solves your problem, you can accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in....thanks.